# Agora can show text label on camera?

Tags: agora.io

agora live stream platform web host can show text label on camera ?

i not find code or need use third party.

and agora live stream can show speech to text real time ?

i want to show speech to text on device(iOS, android) and have web is host

Answer (score 0):

for showing a label if its to display an implicit property i.e something like username or channel name , you will either have to use Agora RTM or a custom server to serve that information independent of the video stream.

However if its something explicit and you want same text to be displayed across all devices you can display it using native render methods like div on web.

There is a way you can avoid that by overlaying the text on to the video stream itself and send it through AgoraSDK.
Full code and explaination of similar implementation [here](https://medium.com/@aditya.26101/e0269f3143df) , its too big to write here see the blog to get a better understanding and just replace the following in the drawVideo() function

```js
function drawVideo() {
  streamCanvasType.drawImage(
    userElement,
    0,
    0,
    streamCanvas.width,
    streamCanvas.height
  );
  streamCanvasType.rect({x - pos}, {y - pos}, {width - of -label}, 
      {height - of -label})
  streamCanvasType.fillStyle = "color of your label"
  streamCanvasType.font = "{font-size} {font-name}"
  streamCanvasType.fillStyle("Label text", {x - pos}, {y - pos})
}
```

Replace {} with your desired values. You can add any thing you want to canvas mentioned in the blog and it will be sent through as the video.
Same goes for **speech-to-text** if you want to do it on the host by getting the actual transcripted text from some library/package for eg. [Speech to Text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/speech-to-text) and passing it to the html canvas.

Otherwise you will have to use individual implementations for each device, Agora does not provide that functionality at the moment.

For Additional Reference you can find more information on the [AgoraSDK documentation](https://docs.agora.io/en/faq/API%20Reference/web/index.html)